# When I run my app the images are not displayed however the text etc is

Tags: java, android, json, url, android-glide

Below is the part of the code I am using to convert the imageurl into imageView using Glide.

```
@Resolve
    private void onResolved() {
        titleTxt.setText(mInfo.getTitle());
        captionTxt.setText(mInfo.getCaption());
        timeTxt.setText(mInfo.getTime());
        Glide.with(mContext).load(mInfo.getImageUrl()).into(imageView);
```

Below is the json file I am using

```
{
                "title": "Livery Hunting At The Festival Of Speed",
                "image_url": "http://speedhunters-wp-production.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/14045435/goodwood-festivalofspeed-jordanbutters-speedhunters-1652-1200x801.jpg",
                "caption": "The Goodwood Festival of Speed boasts vehicular variety like few other annual gatherings.",
                "time": "13 hours ago"
            }
```

Below I've added my XML for what Im trying to achieve

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_border_on_light">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardElevation="1dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleTxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:textStyle="normal"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/captionTxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:textStyle="normal"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timeTxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:textStyle="normal"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In terms of resizing do I have to resize it in my java classes or resize it by using my XML layout file.

Comment: load image with resize or .override(200, 200)

Comment: @Aodhan please check your json parsing first of all

Comment: add your xml file

Comment: Your image is very large in resolution. Resize it and then try.

Comment: public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
            this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        }

Comment: added xml file @OussemaAroua

Comment: Glide.with(mContext).load(mInfo.getImageUrl()).into(imageView).override(100, 100);

Comment: @Pravin override symbol cannot be resolved.

Comment: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-image-resizing-scaling

Comment: Glide.with(mContext).load(mInfo.getImageUrl()).override(100,100).into(imageView);

Comment: that code worked. however the image still did not display. back to the drawing board

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Glide.with(mContext).load(mInfo.getImageUrl()).override(100,‌​100).into(imageView)‌​;
```